# Using Chrome text synthesis in an offline environment

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text-to-speech

I'm trying to implement text to speech support in a system that is being developed in an offline environment. No Internet access. But it doesn't work.

Is it possible to do use the html5 speech api in offline mode?

Comment: i don't think you can - thats just the way chrome implemented it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870590/cant-chromes-speechsynthesis-work-offline

Comment: Is there a way to add local voices? Cause all of the voices on my station are with localService = false