# How to make Chrome's speechSynthesis to work offline?

Tags: google-chrome, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, webspeech-api, speechsynthesizer

I have referred the below link for chrome speechSynthesis offline but could not figure out how to do it?

[Can't Chrome's speechSynthesis work offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870590/cant-chromes-speechsynthesis-work-offline)

When I execute speechSynthesis.getVoices() all voices have localService : false.

I understand that speech synthesizer has to be installed locally, Hence I have installed eSpeak speech synthesizer for Ubuntu 14.10, But could not understand what has to be done next. 
speechSynthesis.getVoices() still fetches localService : false.

Any idea how to make localService : true?