# explore voice capability in Microsoft chat bot

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, direct-line-botframework

I have chat bot developed using Microsoft  bot frame work in , in chat bot we have a option for customer to ask a question for that we need to make it voice enabled as of now we are using node.js and azure for development . i wanted to know how we can achieve it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On google chrome, mic can be enabled easily. Google chrome will also translate the voice for you. First follow below link, see if you are using same framework : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat-speech?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Post that following link can also help enabling the voice. [Can't Chrome's speechSynthesis work offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870590/cant-chromes-speechsynthesis-work-offline)

You can enable voice on Firefox as well using bing translate. This link will help you: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1141