# add voices to speechSynthesis

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, text-to-speech

when I run `speechSynthesis.getVoices()` on different devices there are different number of voices available (even on the same build, my Mac has 350 voices but my friend's has only 70)
How can I add voice packs to the browser?

Note: some devices it doesn't work on the first try, but after a day or two the voice pack gets added (I think). can someone explain whats going on

specifically, I want to add the Microsoft kn-IN lang pack to the Edge browser

Comment: This might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29898576/10249176

Answer (score 0):

The voice lists are different on different devices and browsers. It is dependent upon the user agent/device because that is [how it is specified](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/#dom-speechsynthesis-getvoices).

If you want to add voice to speechSynthesis, I think you can only add it on client side. In my test, it's related with language and voice packages installed in OS. For example, on Windows, if I install new voice packages under "Time & language > Speech", it will show in `speechSynthesis.getVoices()` after restarting the browser. On other OS, you can try to find if there's similar setting which can install language/voice packages.

Comment: it's weird actually, initially, it was not working, but later the voice pack was added I think and started working. But after I cleared cookies, cache etc it stopped working again.
This means there is some way to add the voices, and the browser seems to add it silently after a failed utterance for a language

Comment: I don't find a way to add voice programmatically. Maybe you can try some 3rd party speech API.